# Automorphism groups of 4-dimensional Complex Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, linear-transformations, lie-algebras

Where can I find a published paper concerning with the automorphism group of 
*4-dimensional **complex** Lie algebras*? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A good start would be to have a classification of those Lie algebras to begin with. Do you have that? The simple part, if it exists, is easy, but I guess there are "many" solvable ones.

Answer (score 2):

There is a PhD-thesis on [Automorphisms of Lie Algebras](https://www.surrey.ac.uk/maths/files/pgr/Theses/thesis_RGray.pdf) by
Robert James Gray, which contains the classification of real Lie algebras and their automorphism groups up to dimension $6$, but also has references for the much easier case of complex $4$-dimensional Lie algebras. A classification of the complex Lie algebra in dimension $4$ is in my paper [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_10_deg_4di.pdf).